# Pronunciation of damning

Tags: pronunciation

I want to pronounce damning 'dam- ning' but dictionaries including the unabridged OED show the only correct pronunciation should be 'damn-ing'?

Comment: In UK we don't pronounce the "n". We say **damming**.

Comment: The dictionaries have given you a consistent answer - do you think it's wrong?

Comment: There are no doubt those who will produce damning critiques of this, but to my ear there's no discernible difference (here in the US) between "damning" and "damming" (or between "damn" and "dam").

Comment: In Canadian English, it's a homonym with "damming", too.  The N is silent in all contexts of the use of the word "damn", except "damnation" where it is fully pronounced.

Comment: In my own experience I have heard some use the word 'damning' and deliberately pronounce the 'n'. My surmise is that such people do not, commonly, use 'hard' language and when they want to use the word 'damning' they are demonstrating that their use is not as a swear word, but that they are using the word in the sense of 'condemn'.

Comment: I think I like Nigel J's answer.   Could we accept that damming is a verb and dam-ning is the adjective?

Comment: @ArchibaldJuniper - You don't think "damning" is a verb??

Comment: 'Damming' is what beavers do. OED -->http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=damming&_searchBtn=Search

Comment: If they were pronounced differently we'd lose a whole slew of jokes.

Comment: The NRA is damn-ing gun control, the outcome is dam-ning!

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that in a typical modern English accent, as a general rule the addition of the inflectional ending *-ing* never causes an irregular phonological change like this to the pronunciation of the preceding part. (There may be regular phonetic or phonological changes, like the change of voiceless t to flap t in an American accent or the pronunciation of an [r] sound that is not pronounced in the base word in a British accent.) There are a number of derived words like *damnation* that are pronounced with /mn/, but the inflected form *damning* is not. So the pronunciation of *damning* with /mn/ would be considered "incorrect".

The OED apparently does countenance the use of /mn/ in certain derived nouns ending in *-ing*: the entry for the noun *limning* ("Illuminating of manuscripts, etc." or "painting") says "/ˈlɪmɪŋ//ˈlɪmnɪŋ/".

The pronunciation of words like this was more uncertain in the past.

John Walker's *Critical Pronunciation Dictionary* of 1791, a prescriptive pronunciation guide, shows /mn/ in words like *[damnable](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n202/mode/2up/search/damn)* and the disyllabic pronunciation of *damned,* but /m/ without /n/ in *damn* and the monosyllabic pronunciation of *damned.* Walker gives the following rule for words ending in *-ing*:

> 411. *N* is mute when it ends a syllable, and is preceded by *m,* as in *hymn, limn, solemn, column, autumn, condemn, contemn.* In *hym-ning* and *lim-ning* the the *n* is generally pronounced, and sometimes, in very solemn speaking, in *condem-ning* and *contem-ning;* but, in both cases, contrary to analogy, which forbids any sound in the participle that was not in the verb.

(p. 49)

Comment: To my ear, *damn* sounds slightly different (to *dam*), but that might be because it’s usually used for emphasis anyway ...